# Find the matrix that associated to a given quadratic form

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

Please help me complete my answer and find the matrix associated to a given quadratic form, here is my work and effort on that

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF8eb.jpg)]

Here's my attempt to answer it

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFfaN.jpg)]

Comment: Again, it would be great if you'd make some effort to write down you work using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that for a skew symmetric matrix $S$

$$v^TSv=0 \quad \forall x$$

and that

$$v^T(A+S)v= v^TAv+v^TSv$$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but i'm sorry i still don't understand what matrix A and S standing for, are those equal to matrix A and B or B and B'?

Comment: @A.D.P Do you know what is a skew symmetric matrix? Refer to [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix)

Comment: Is it when matrix A' = -A?

Comment: @A.D.P Yes exactly!

Comment: okay got it. Thank you so much for your respond :)

Comment: @A.D.P You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @A.D.P To sumarize your $A$ is fine, now you can define $B=A+S$. Let try with a numerical example.